# Como alterar um "Game Object" existente?

Tags: unity3d

Estou começando agora com o Unity3D e para isso peguei o exemplo que vem com o pacote, o `car.unity`.

Eu li muita documentação, mas não consegui fazer algo muito simples...

1. **Como alterar a forma de  um já existente**?
   não estou falando de cor ou de textura, ou mesmo de posição, **mas a forma mesmo**!
2. Não tem uma ferramenta "interna" do unity pra fazer isso?
3. **OUTRA COISA**: tentei "exportar" essa "pista" , para **poder editar por uma ferramenta externa** (como o blender) mas me frustrei novamente,  não consegui fazer nem isso.

Para ser mais direta, eu **gostaria de simplesmente trocar o trajeto** da pista
colocar mais curvas, mais retas, coisas assim!
E como ja tem uma pista la, gostaria de "atualizar" aquela que já existe!

Obrigada!

Comment: Você vai precisar de um modelador 3D pra fazer isso. O Unity Editor não edita modelos 3D.

Comment: imaginei isso.... e para tanto estou usando o Blender... na verdade foi minha primeira tentativa...